# How to write a character in python html

Tags: python, html, django

I want "V" in html page when I add value in database

```
<td>{{stud.MaxVolt}}</td>
```

one way is I write V with database's value but I want it to be written automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just do {{stud.MaxVolt}}V .
The V will be in the template not in database anymore .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You append it at after the template variable, so:

```
<td>{{ stud.MaxVolt }}V</td>
```

or with a [*non-breaking space* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in between:

```
<td>{{ stud.MaxVolt }}&nbsp;V</td>
```

this will normally prevent that `V` is put on another line, so it will not split between `42` and `V` in `42 V`.

> one way is I write V with database's value.

I would really advise *not* to use a `CharField` for numerical data, but a [**`DecimalField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField) or [**`FloatField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField) for data with a decimal dot, or [**`IntegerField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) for integral data.

Answer (score -1):

Please just do `<td>{{stud.MaxVolt}}V</td>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).